# IPhone-updating an array on button click

Tags: iphone

I am new to IPhone development.

When I click on the button programmatically a new image in an IMAGEVIEW is displayed on the UIView. I want to store the images in some container and then use them later.

Here is my source code for creating images through UIGraphics.

```
   if ([shape isEqualToString:@"Rectangle"])
    {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(100.0, 100.0));
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);    
        CGRect main =CGRectMake(15.0, 15.0, 70.0, 30.0);
        CGContextFillRect(context, main);   

        CGRect topSeat1 = CGRectMake(15.0, 0.0, 15.0, 13.0);
        CGRect topSeat2 = CGRectMake(42.5, 0.0, 15.0, 13.0);
        CGRect topSeat3 = CGRectMake(70.0, 0.0, 15.0, 13.0);

        CGRect leftSeat = CGRectMake(0.0, 22.5, 13.0, 15.0);

        CGRect rightSeat = CGRectMake(87.0, 22.5, 13.0, 15.0);


        [[UIColor redColor]set];
        //UIRectFill(main);
        UIRectFill(topSeat1);
        UIRectFill(topSeat2);
        UIRectFill(topSeat3);
        UIRectFill(leftSeat);
        UIRectFill(rightSeat);
        UIRectFrame(main);

        [[UIColor blackColor]set];
        UIRectFrame(topSeat1);
        UIRectFrame(topSeat2);
        UIRectFrame(topSeat3);
        UIRectFrame(leftSeat);
        UIRectFrame(rightSeat);

        UIImage * image = [[UIImage alloc]init];
        image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        myImage=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        [self.view addSubview:myImage];
        [myImage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

        [arrayOfImages addObject:myImage];

    }
```

However the image is displayed but when I again click on the button, another images gets displayed but the older one on the UIView becomes static and I can't do anything to it.

I would prefer some code.

All I ask is:

1. How to store them, so that on every button click the container gets populated or updated with UIImageViews.
2. How to restore them later.

Answer (score 0):

I probably did not understand your question completely, if you just want to store the images for reference at a later point of time you can add them to an array.

```
NSMutableArray *imagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[imagesArray addObject: image];
```

If you would like to access the images later, you can do it through the index

```
[imagesArray objectAtIndex: indexOfTheImage];
```

Comment: dont forget to release the imagesArray when you are done  [imagesArray release]

Answer (score -1):

I would do it like this:

```
- (IBAction)button {

    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 240, 40, 40)];
    [image setImage:@"yourimage.png"];
    [self.view addSubview:image];
    [myArray addObject:image];

}
```

You'l have to use: `[imagesArray objectAtIndex: indexOfTheImage];`

As the **1st** answer says.

hope i helped :)

Comment: Flagged for promoting the user's blog. Please don't randomly promote your blog in an answer, it's not acceptable in this community.

Comment: oh sorry, i really didn't know. I'll delete the answer.